# binding a control to parent model in EditorFor template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is the situation: 
I have a view bound to the parent model. In this view, I am calling EditorFor and passing the child object. But in that EditorFor, I want to bind a control of the parent model. How can i do it? I also need to bind the validation control. I created the property in the parent model.

```
@model ParentModel
   //Parent view 
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  { 
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
       @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Entity, new { CountiesServed = Model.CountiesServed, Types = Model.EntityTypes, CommunicationMethods = Model.CommunicationMethods, OrganizationTypes = Model.OrganizationTypes })

            <p class="form-actions" style="text-align:right;">
                <button type="submit" >Next &#187;</button>
            </p>
   }
```

In the child view - I want to bind a control not to its view model but to the parent view //model. 
    @model ChildModel

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.somechildentityproperty) 

//But how to do something like this? 
@Html.EditorFor(//ParentModel property) ???
```

Comment: I dont THINK this would work. You would have to manually create this realtionship without using helpers.

Answer (score 1):

If the `EditorFor` is not using the property used as it's Model, then that's a warning flag that it should actually be a Partial View and **not** and `EditorFor`. That way you can easily pass in the parent model.

Otherwise, keeping an `EditorFor` you'd have to put the Parent model on the child property, which is **messy** to say the least.

Comment: EditorFor is using its model. Just that I have a table in that and one row needs a value from the parent model. If I use a partial view, I cant align the property I need in the way, the webpage is expected to show the fields.

Comment: @dotnetter Maybe it's a good idea to put a foreign key (for the property) on the child in the database, then in your model? Sounds like a missing piece in your database design.

Comment: Nope. This property is from the Junction table. There is FK but it is many to many so it is in a junction table and I am using NetTiers ORM.

Comment: @dotnetter Ah right, then you may be best to put the Parent model as a property on the Child model.

Comment: Oh, does it do the client side validations, etc, if I do so? I will try it and post my comment. Thanks mattytommo